# Assigning values to a dynamically resized array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, preserve, vba

I am trying to populate a two dimensional array of ranges. I don't know how big the array will need to be, so I am using the ReDim and Preserve functions to dynamically re-size the array as required.

I am encountering runtime error 91: "Object variable or With block variable not set" when I run the code.

I am not an experienced coder, but I have managed to isolate the error, and am sure it is coming from the pseudo code below.

Can anyone see any mistakes I have made that would produce the runtime error?

```
    Dim ArrayName() as Range
    Dim counter as Integer

    If condition = True Then

        counter = counter + 1

        ReDim Preserve ArrayName(0, counter - 1) 
        ArrayName(0, counter - 1) = Cells(counter, counter) 'I get a runtime error here

    End If
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store ranges within your array you need to add `Set` before problem line in this way:

```
Set ArrayName(0, counter - 1) = Cells(counter, counter)
```

But if you want to store values of the cells you need to change declaration line to this:

```
Dim ArrayName() as Double 'or String or Variant depending on value type you need to keep in array
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple! Thank you so much.